Unable to scrape XHR elements from webpage (python)
I've already searched for similar questions but due to errors on deprecated methods I'm still not able to solve this.
I just need to extract the JSON provided by the only xhr element in this page:
https://certificatoricreditors.mimit.gov.it/Consultazione
The xhr is named Consultazione?..... and I'm totally unable to extract it. I have no code, only trials from other sources like:
How to scrape from XHR in Chrome ( Python ) (404 error)
Scraping UPDATED source code from XHR response of a website (no code provided)
etc

Here is one way to get that information:
import pandas as pd
import requests

s = requests.Session()
headers = {
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}
s.headers.update(headers)

s.get('https://certificatoricreditors.mimit.gov.it/Consultazione')
r = s.get('https://certificatoricreditors.mimit.gov.it/Consultazione?handler=Albo&skip=0&take=5000&requireTotalCount=true')
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['data'])
print(f'There are {df.shape[0]} total records')
print(df.head())

Result in terminal:
There are 304 total records
IdSoggetto  FlagPersonaGiuridica    Denominazione   CognomeRagioneSociale   Nome    CodiceFiscale   PartitaIva  DataIscrizione  NumeroIscrizione    SiglaProvinciaRecapitoProfessionale ... SettoreInnovazioneTecnologicaDichiarato DichSettoreDesignRisultanteProgetti SettoreDesignRisultanteProgetti DichSettoreRicercaSviluppoRisultanteProgetti    SettoreRicercaSviluppoRisultanteProgetti    DichSettoreInnovazioneTecnologicaRisultanteProgetti SettoreInnovazioneTecnologicaRisultanteProgetti PecImpresa  TitoloLaurea    Recapiti
0   1   False   CONZA MARIA LUISA   CONZA   MARIA LUISA ************834A    None    2024-05-10T00:00:00 1   [FR]    ... [10. INDUSTRIE ALIMENTARI, 32. ALTRE INDUSTRIE...   True    []  True    [Scienze ingegneristiche e tecnologiche - Altr...   True    [72. RICERCA SCIENTIFICA E SVILUPPO]    None    LAUREA MAGISTRALE IN CHIMICA E FARMACIA, LAURE...   [{'IdRecapitoProfessionale': 190, 'Denominazio...
1   2   False   PERSANO ADORNO GIUSEPPE ROSARIO PERSANO ADORNO  GIUSEPPE ROSARIO    ************036M    None    2024-05-10T00:00:00 2   [RN]    ... [10. INDUSTRIE ALIMENTARI, 13. INDUSTRIE TESSI...   True    []  True    [Scienze ingegneristiche e tecnologiche - Altr...   True    [14. CONFEZIONE DI ARTICOLI DI ABBIGLIAMENTO; ...   None    Laurea Magistrale in Ingegneria Energetica e N...   [{'IdRecapitoProfessionale': 2, 'Denominazione...
2   3   False   PETRICCA Riccardo   Petricca    Riccardo    ************838B    None    2024-05-10T00:00:00 3   [FR]    ... [58. ATTIVITÀ EDITORIALI, 61. TELECOMUNICAZION...   False   []  True    [Scienze ingegneristiche e tecnologiche - Altr...   True    []  None    INGEGNERIA DELLE TELECOMUNICAZIONI V.O. [{'IdRecapitoProfessionale': 3, 'Denominazione...
3   4   False   LASAPONARA ROSA LASAPONARA  ROSA    ************326N    None    2024-05-10T00:00:00 4   [PZ]    ... [01. COLTIVAZIONI AGRICOLE E PRODUZIONE DI PRO...   True    []  True    [Scienze ingegneristiche e tecnologiche - Altr...   True    [62. PRODUZIONE DI SOFTWARE, CONSULENZA INFORM...   None    Laurea magistrale in Ingegneria elettronica [{'IdRecapitoProfessionale': 4, 'Denominazione...
4   5   False   PIANTI ANDREA   PIANTI  ANDREA  ************501N    None    2024-05-10T00:00:00 5   [PO]    ... [01. COLTIVAZIONI AGRICOLE E PRODUZIONE DI PRO...   True    [31. FABBRICAZIONE DI MOBILI]   True    [Scienze ingegneristiche e tecnologiche - Altr...   True    [25. FABBRICAZIONE DI PRODOTTI IN METALLO (ESC...   None    Laurea magistrale in Ingegneria per l'Ambiente...   [{'IdRecapitoProfessionale': 5, 'Denominazione...
5 rows × 25 columns

EDIT: I removed the timestamp from the url, as it will still work and now it won't change, and also increased the total number of records, ensuring all are being returned.
Requests documentation can be found here, and for Pandas'. go here.

But you manually put the url of the xhr element, but It will change everytime that you make the request, it's not static

It actually is static, @Federicofkt. You can remove the last bit of the url, and it will still return the results. Answer updated, and it will also return all available records now.
